# telnet to several devices and return command output

Tags: python, telnet

I am running python (ver. 2.6.2) on a linux machine and need to be able to telnet into a long list of devices (about 300) send the command "sho ser" and return the resulting output of that command to a file and each sequential device down the list then add it's output to a new line. All the devices are listed on separate lines in a file

I found some code that got me started from another post but i am not sure where to go from here. i can open the list i have called "hostlist" but im not sure how to tell python to telnet to one device, run the command, exit, then go to the next. any help would be greatly appreciated

```
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib

f = open('hostlist', 'r')

HOST = "%s" % f
user = raw_input("Enter your login name: ")
password = getpass.getpass()

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

tn.read_until("login: ")
tn.write(user + "\n")
if password:
    tn.read_until("Password: ")
    tn.write(password + "\n")

tn.write("show ver\n")
tn.write("exit\n")

print tn.read_all()
```

receiving this error

```
Enter your login name: K3grb6hj9ld93a2
Password: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/telnetlib.py", line 209, in __init__
    self.open(host, port, timeout)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/telnetlib.py", line 225, in open
    self.sock = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 498, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Comment: What's the problem? Are there any errors, exceptions, have you tested the code?

Comment: It's just a matter of writing a loop on `f`... You know about loops, right?

Comment: Im getting the error shown above when i try to run it. i know how to make a loop but im not sure how to implement it. i have the name of the file to open as hostlist and tried changing the HOST object as the output of the hostlist opening but always get the same error.

added errors to original post due to space contraints